# How to import variables of state from useSelector?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

This is my very simple reducer:

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initState = {
  red: 0,
  green: 0,
  blue: 0,
};

const colorSlice = createSlice({
  name: "color",
  initialState: initState,
  reducers: {
    controlRed(state, action) {
      state.red = action.payload;
    },
    controlGreen(state, action) {
      state.green = action.payload;
    },
    controlBlue(state, action) {
      state.blue = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const { controlRed, controlGreen, controlBlue } = colorSlice.actions;

export default colorSlice.reducer;
```

It works good but how would I go about importing the (`red`, `green`, `blue`) state variables in my other components?

I did this and it doesn't work.

```
  const { red, green, blue } = useSelector((state) => state.colors);
```

It gives me this error.
[image]

I am new to redux toolkit.
How should the useSelector look like?

EDIT:
This is my configureStore:

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import reducer from "./color";

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: reducer,
});

export default store;
```

Comment: What do you import and name that reducer in your root reducer when you pass it to `combineReducers`? I believe the state slice will have *that* name. Can you include that code? Do you have the redux-dev-tools and browser extension installed? That could help you see what the state shape and structure is.

Comment: @DrewReese I am using the configureStore so I don't need to worry about ``combineReducers`` . I added the code at the end.

Comment: @DrewReese Yes I have the browser extension installed and I am using redux toolkit

Comment: Right, ok, I'm still more familiar with the older react-redux (but catching up). If I had to guess, it's the name of the reducer function, so something like, `const { red, green, blue } = useSelector((state) => state.color);` not `colors`. This appears to be a simple typo.

Comment: Ya, I tried that too but it doesn't work and gives out the same error. I'm going through the docs, maybe I'll find something there.

Comment: What is the state shape when you examine it in the dev tools? Think you could create a simple codesandbox that reproduces this issue to share in your question? Often when distilling a codebase down to a minimal example the error/issue/bug will pop out and become apparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where should the .colors come from?

The color values are not further nested in a "colors" object, they can just be accessed directly, e.g.

```
  const { red, green, blue } = useSelector((state) => state);
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you so much. I see the problem now.